# Multilingual site and Google search

Tags: google, google-search, multilingual

I have a multilingual site with only one domain `www.mydomain.com`, this domain serves content in English and Norwegian. And language is handled using a server side session parameter, which is triggered by a click on a button on my website.

My problem is that Google only find and index my English version of the website, and not the Norwegian part of it.
After looking for a solution I came over this post on Google:
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192

From what I read there, it looks like I can't use sessions to control language, and that I should use one of these solutions:

- `en.domain.com` - `no.domain.com`
- `www.domain.com/en` - `www.domain.com/no`
- `www.domain.com` - `www.domain.no`

Is this true, or is it possible to get Google to index my Norwegian and English content by using my session parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the translated versions separate URLs if you want Google to index them. From Google's ["Working with multilingual websites"](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html) blog post:

> To make all of your site's content more crawlable, avoid automatic
>   redirections based on the user's perceived language. These
>   redirections could prevent users (and search engines) from viewing all
>   the versions of your site.
>
> And last but not least, keep the content for each language on separate
>   URLs - **don't use cookies [or sessions] to show translated versions.**

Comment: You may also want to add [rel=alternate links](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189077) to cross-link the translated pages.  However, do _not_ use rel=canonical in a situation like this; that's for when [you have the same content on multiple pages, with only the navigation boilerplate translated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/unifying-content-under-multilingual.html).

Comment: Thanx for your answer, guess that concludes it, and I need to change my url's. No workaround for my session controlled site :P

Answer (score -3):

Try to insert this in to the Norwegian site's header :

```
<meta name="language" content="norwegian">
```

[metatags.info](http://www.metatags.info/meta_name_language)

or

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="no">
```

[seoconsultants.com](http://www.seoconsultants.com/meta-tags/language)

I would do both. Just in case. and Put the English one in to...

Comment: -1: Google has stated that they effectively ignore these meta values - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0610ddf168b8d424&hl=en and http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192&topic=2370587&ctx=topic